# In iOS, how do you embed images inline with text (in a UITextView)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview

How can you create a UITextView that can have images inline? I looked up NSAttributedString, but it seems iOS does not support image attachments. Any ideas for an editable text view that can display images (I suppose RTF would do this)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The only method I am aware of is to use a `UIWebView`.  There is no way to add images to a `UITextView`, unfortunately, just plain text.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too, but do you have any thoughts on how to make it editable?

Comment: Of course you can make a UIWebView editable.  You might just have to use some HTML/javascript/css to make it all work nicely.

Comment: Blah. That's what I was afraid of. I wish there was better rich text support in iOS. Oh well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I can't give you an easy fix.  But will you accept this answer as if you are satisfied with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [NSTextAttachment](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextAttachment_Class/index.html) class. It lets you insert images inline of text.

I found an example of this in a cool project here: https://github.com/dzog/ImgGlyph. ImgGlyph provides `UITextView` and `UILabel` subclass implementations that help you replace specific strings with images and ensures they're sized correctly with respect to the text surrounding it.